# Theme issue on mobile

Tags: bug

On mobile (specifically android 4, chrome)  on both coffee and meta.coffee has an issue with the bar that has Questions, Tags, Users, etc.

The hightlighted option has a red underline, but the text almost disappears - it is very very close to the backgroud color and invisible unless fully zoomed in.

Comment: Tablet or phone?

Comment: Phone - samsung galaxy note 4.  Havent tried on my tablet.

Comment: The browser or the mobile app?  If you are using the beta version of the mobile app, it would be appropriate to post this at Meta.SE under [Help use test the Stack Exchange Android tablet app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245731/help-us-test-the-stack-exchange-android-tablet-app).  I also have a Galaxy Note 4 with the beta, and I haven't noticed a problem.

Comment: Not the app.  Chrome on android.